# How to add multiple namespaces in xmlXPathRegisterNs (libxml2) in cpp

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I am working on parsing a XML document using libxml2. I have successfully added a namespace as follows:

```
   if(xmlXPathRegisterNs(context,  BAD_CAST "rdf", BAD_CAST "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#") != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to register NS with prefix");
    return NULL;
}
```

As the XML I am working with has multilple namespaces, how can I efficiently add that as part of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `xmlXPathRegisterNs` multiple times, once for each prefix/namespace pair.